# Concurrent processing of threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, subprocess

I am trying to run different bash scripts on remote nodes using python multi-threading. First thread t1 triggers script1 and this should be completed first before other threads. Then, second thread t2 must trigger 3 more scripts. I have used Popen() because, it need not wait until the script is completely executed. So, concurrently all these 3 scripts must be in running mode now. Then, after 200secs another thread must be started which triggers a different script. I could even use Timer and run a thread after 200secs, but its not working for me sometimes.

Therefore, in my case all the threads should be running concurrently except the first thread t1. So, all scripts script2,script3,script4 need to be executed simultaneously and the script5 should be executed after 200secs.

I am confused, if I should use python multiprocessing or python multithreading here. So far I have only tried with python multithreading.

Each script here is run on multiple remote nodes parallely using python vxargs program. I am capturing cpu utilization using top command in script2, the length of packets transferred on to the network using tcpdump in script3. At a certain point I need to kill these two processes(top, tcpdump), so I use script5 to kill them using the kill command. If I run these scripts on like 10 remote nodes, I get the results only on may be 4nodes. There might be the problem with handling one of these script2,script3, or script5 and most importantly handling script5 because it seems to me that script5 doesn't kill the top, tcpdump processes. I want to make it stable i.e to work for all remote nodes. Here is my code:

(In my code, file1.txt has the list of all the remote nodes, where my scripts are being run using vxargs)

```
class plThreads (threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,threadID,name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        print "starting thread "+self.name
        pyFunction(self.name)
        print "Exiting thread "+self.name

def pyFunction(threadName):
    if threadName == 'thread1':
        global startTime
        startTime=time.time()
        subprocess.Popen("python vxargs -a file1.txt ssh -l user_name {} 'bash script1.sh'", shell=True)

    elif threadName == 'thread2': 
        subprocess.Popen("python vxargs -a file1.txt ssh -l user_name {} 'bash script2.sh'", shell=True)

        subprocess.Popen("python vxargs -a file1.txt ssh -l user_name {} 'bash script3.sh'", shell=True)

        subprocess.Popen("python vxargs -a file1.txt ssh -l user_name {} 'bash script4.sh'", shell=True)

    elif threadName == 'thread3':
        subprocess.call("python vxargs -a file1.txt ssh -l user_name {} 'bash script5.sh'", shell=True)

t1=plThreads(1,"thread1")
t1.start()
t1.join()

t2=plThreads(2, "thread2")
t2.start()

while(1):
    timediff = time.time()-startTime
    if timediff >= 200:
        t3=plThreads(3,"thread3")
        t3.start()
        break
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What doesn't work with your code? Is that the thread3 sometime doesn't start?

Comment: If you don't give any details about what doesn't work it is very hard try to help you. I found at least 3 candidates but I need more details to be sure and fill an answer.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico I have updated my question with more details